# How to load printf from UCRT DLLs?

Tags: c++, dll, crt

I am trying to dynamically load `printf` from `ucrtbase.dll`, but `GetProcAddress` is returning NULL. Other functions like `malloc` and `puts` work, but not `printf`.

```
int main() {
    const char* path = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\10\\Redist\\10.0.19041.0\\ucrt\\DLLs\\x64\\ucrtbase.dll";
    HINSTANCE handle = LoadLibraryA(path);
    if (handle != NULL) {
        auto func = GetProcAddress(handle, "printf");
        if (func != NULL) {
            // Do something
        }
        else {
            printf("Could not find function.");
        }
        FreeLibrary(handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some underlying problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: This is accurate.  printf() is defined in the stdio.h header, it calls `__stdio_common_vfprintf` in ucrtbase.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am trying to make a FFI. When there is a foreign function call I just look up the function in the appropriate DLL. But based on the other comment it looks like I'll have to make my own `printf` wrapper that calls `__stdio_common_vfprintf`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.